# Module parse error for an NPM package

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I'm receiving a weird error at the build time utilizing Webpack. The error in question is referring to [Got's](https://www.npmjs.com/package/got) `package.json` file that I'm importing.

```
Module parse failed: .../node_modules/got/package.json Unexpected token (2:8)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
SyntaxError: Unexpected token (2:8)
```

Curious to what is causing this and if this is on my end or Got's end.

**Node version**: v4.2.0

**NPM version**: 2.14.7

Comment: @Jonathan.Brink updated question

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are importing a json, but don't have the appropriate loader configured. In your webpack-confing add a json loader to your loaders. It should look something like this:

```
var config = {
  ....
  module: {
    loaders: [
      ...
      {
        test: /\.json/,
        loader: 'json'
      }
    ]
  },
  ....
}
```

Comment: I've never seen this done in any of the examples of webpack-config, why now add that just for this one package when all of them have `package.json` files?

Comment: In your question you said '... package.json that I'm importing', i thought you imported it. If you just imported the package, then it's maybe a problem that you forgot to exclude the the `node_modules` from the `webpack.config`.
Add `exclude: /node_modules/` to the javascript loader.